# How to create a folder tree from an array?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a folder tree, for example from such an array:

```
["nightmare", "profile", "cover"]
```

Using this code:

```
$folders = ["nightmare", "profile", "cover"];
$directory = './images/users';

foreach ($folders as $folder) {
    if (!file_exists($directory . '/' . $folder)) {
        $directory .= '/' . $folder;
        mkdir($directory, 0777, TRUE);
        file_put_contents($directory . '/' . 'index.html', "");
    }
}
```

But, if any folder from the "folders" array already exists, then in this case the next folder will be created outside the main directory.

That is, if with such a structure:

```
images
 ┣ users
 ┃ ┃nightmare
 ┃ ┃ ┗ profile
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┗ index.html
```

We will get such a result:

```
images
 ┣ users
 ┃ ┣ nightmare
 ┃ ┃ ┗ profile
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┣ profile
 ┃ ┃ ┣ cover
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┗ index.html
```

And if you remove **IF**:

```
$folders = ["nightmare", "profile", "cover"];
$directory = './images/users';

foreach ($folders as $folder) {
    $directory .= '/' . $folder;
    mkdir($directory, 0777, TRUE);
    file_put_contents($directory . '/' . 'index.html', "");
}
```

In this case, if any folder exists, a warning will be thrown:

> PHP Warning: mkdir(): File exists

Despite the warning, the operation will be successful, and non-existent and required folders will be created. However, I am interested in whether it is possible to solve this problem in a normal way? That is, without a warning from the mkdir function.

Of course, it would be possible to solve the problem without a cycle:

```
mkdir($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $folders), 0777, TRUE);
```

But, I need each newly created folder to have a specific file or files, as an example `index.html`. Therefore, the one-line function above is not suitable.

Comment: If you are going to use the `TRUE` parameter to allow `mkdir()` to recursively create missing folders, why create the directory on every iteration?

Comment: @mickmackusa, I don't have much experience with PHP, so I probably make mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is concat.
Just use this code:

```
$folders = ["nightmare", "profile", "cover"];
$directory = './images/users';

foreach ($folders as $folder) {
    $directory .= '/' . $folder;
    if (!file_exists($directory)) {
        mkdir($directory, 0777);
        file_put_contents($directory . '/' . 'index.html', "");
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

In the for structure when you check the existance of directory using if it will not change `$directory` value. So it will create next folder one directory upper.
To solve this we update `$directory` value before checking. As result if directory exists it won't try to create one and just goes in to create the nested one!